# How can i login using gapi and get user info in react?

Tags: reactjs, google-api-js-client

> i have using gpai to login with google in my react project i have add
> this two script in my index.html

```
<script
      src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init"
      async
      defer
    ></script>
    <meta
      name="google-signin-client_id"
      content="client id"
    />
```

> then i have create login.js page here is my code :-

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
function Login() {
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

but i cant able to call this signIn function .can anyone help me out to this problem.